# location delegate not firing

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I'm trying to get the user location. I added the coreLocation framework, and implamented the start location method and the delegate. 
The problem that the delegate function just doesn't fired.

LocationManager.h :

```
@interface LocationManager : NSObject<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property(strong,nonatomic)CLLocationManager *locationManager;

-(void)startLocaitonService;

@end
```

LocationManager.m :

```
@implementation LocationManager 

-(void)startLocaitonService
{
    _locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
    _locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

}
@end
```

I'm have a breakpoint in the delegate function but nothing happens

Comment: What version of iOS?

Comment: 7.1 version @trojanfoe

Answer (score 0):

That delegate method was deprecated in iOS 6.0.

From [the class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:):

> **Deprecation Statement**
>
> Use `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` instead.